# I use a function with return type double and i want to return nothing (not zero)

Tags: c#, class, return-type

I use a function with a **double** as return type and I want to return nothing (not zero).

In case of error I want the console to output the error message only (but it won't allow me as it requires value to be returned).

My code looks like this:

```
class Stos
{
    public static double[] Sztos;
    public int position = 0;

    public Stos(int size)
    {
        Sztos = new double[size];
    }

    public void push(double value)
    {
        if (position <= Sztos.Length - 1)
        {
            Sztos[position] = value;
            position++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are trying to insert a value to a stack that is full");
        }
    }
    public double pop()
    {
        if (--position<0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no elements in Stack");
            //I should return something here but I only want error message
        }
        else
        return Sztos[position];
    }


}
```

Comment: You could throw an exception. Or return a `NaN`.

Comment: You can use nullable double (double?) -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw an exception if the precondition is violated e.g.

```
public double pop()
{
    if (--position<0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no elements in Stack");
    }
    else
    return Sztos[position];
}
```

you should also give the client a way to check the operation is valid e.g.

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get { return position <= 0; }
}
```

Comment: As far as I comprehend the first part of your answer what does the "IsEmpty" field do ?

Comment: @ThePigeon109 - It allows the client to avoid an exception when calling `pop` by allowing them to check if the operation will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
    public double? pop()
    {
        if (--position < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no elements in Stack");
            //I should return something here but I only want error message
            return null;
        }
        else
            return Sztos[position];
    }
```

now pop as nullable double, you can check if is null or not and try convert double? to double